# google.script.run.withSuccessHandler returns undefined. How can I fix it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get last row of a spreadsheet and put it into a Sidebar. Here is my code:

**code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Demo')
      .addItem('DemoChild', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}


function showSidebar(){
    var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('a.html');
    widget.setTitle('Demo');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(widget);
}

function getRowsUsed(sheetname){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var range = sheet.getSheetByName(sheetname)
  var rangeStartEnd = range.getLastRow()
    
  return rangeStartEnd;
};
```

**a.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function getValue(a) {
      return a;
    }
    
    function doIt(){
      var res = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getValue).getRowsUsed('Sheet1');
      alert(res);
    }
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>
    <script>doIt();</script>
  </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Instead of a number, it returns `undefined`. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong. Can someone please help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction)

- Sets a callback function to run if the server-side function returns successfully. The server's return value is passed to the function as the first argument, and the user object (if any) is passed as a second argument.
- Returns a `google.script.run`

The value you are expecting is passed to your assigned callback function which is `getValue(a)`. If you want to check the value returned by `getRowsUsed(sheetname)`, you can display the value of `a` in `getValue(a)` function

**Sample Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function getValue(a) {
      var div = document.getElementById('output');
      div.innerHTML = 'Num of rows = '+ a;
    }
    
    function doIt(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getValue).getRowsUsed('Sheet1');
      
    }
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
  <p>
    <script>doIt();</script>
  </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]